# Display posts by TAG shortcode doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

Please advise.
The goal is to have the shortcode
[featured_posts_by_tag numberposts="5" tags="My-Featured-Post"] display the list of five posts with thumbnails that tagged as 'My-Featured-Post". But it doesn't 'pick up' the 'tags'...

The code is below:

```
<?php
  add_shortcode('featured_posts_by_tag', function($atts) {
      extract(shortcode_atts( array( 
         'post_type' => 'post',
         'numberposts' => 3,
         'tags' => '' ), 
      $atts ));

  $args = [
         'post_type'=> $post_type,
         'numberposts' => $numberposts,
         'fields'=> 'ids'
  ];

  if($tags){ 
     $args['tax_query'] = 
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
          'field' => 'term_id',
          'terms' -> $tags
     );
   }

   $posts = get_posts($args);

   ob_start();

   if($posts) : ?>
      <ul class="featured-posts-by-tag-list">
        <?php foreach($posts as $post_id) : ?>

            <li <?php echo post_class('featured-post-by-tag', $post_id); ?>>
                <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($post_id); ?>">
                  
                  <?php if(has_post_thumbnail($post_id)) : ?>
                    <img <?php echo post_img_src_data(get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id), 'medium'); ?> >
                  <?php endif; ?>
                </a>
                <h4>
                  <a class="featured-post-title" href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($post_id); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($post_id); ?></a>
                </h4>
                <p>
                  <a class="read-more" href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($post_id); ?>">read more ></a>
                </p>
          </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </ul>

   <?php endif;

   $output = ob_get_clean();

   return $output;
   });
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your Array construction :

```
 if($tags){ 
     $args['tax_query'] = 
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
          'field' => 'term_id',
          'terms' => $tags
     );
   }
```

The error was at **'terms' -> $tags** but the good syntax is : **'terms' => $tags**

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I'd corrected '->' but the issue is not resolved (